# Docker docker-compose Unable to Access jarfile specified in Dockerfile

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jar, docker-compose

Everything is fine when I run the commands

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t my_app_name .
docker run -t my_app_name
```

However, if I try to use `docker-compose up`

I receive the error of  `app_1  | Error: Unable to access jarfile /D-1.jar`

I have a project with the file structure of

```
DockerPlayground
  |_build
      |_libs
         |_D-1.jar
  |_src
      |_main
          |_java
              |_com.DockerPlayground
                  My Code Here
  docker-compose.yml
  Dockerfile
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY build/libs/*.jar D-1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/D-1.jar"]
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
    restart: always
```

Comment: Does it help if you change context: "" to context: .
 (don't forget the dot)

Comment: @Vahid it does not, same error.